# How to export a class and have an interface in the same file?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following TypeScript file:

```
// declare a jquery plugin, so that it can be used in the class
interface JQueryStatic {
  plot(arg: any, arg2: any, arg3: any): JQueryStatic;
}

export class Foo {
  public plotThings() {
    $.plot('#myDiv');  // ERROR HERE
                       // TS2339  (TS) Property 'plot' does not exist on type 'JQueryStatic'
  }              
}
```

So it fails to find the `plot` method. However, if I remove `export` from the class declaration, the file compiles fine.

So, how can I have both the JQueryStatic interface (to be able to use a jQuery plugin) and an exported class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just extend an interface declared somewhere else like that. Typescript namespaces everything per file, so it has no way to know you mean the global interface declared by the jQuery type definitions.

So create a `jquery.d.ts` file to have your jQuery specific extensions in and add this, making it clear you mean the global one.

```
declare global {
    interface JQuery {
        plot(arg: any, arg2: any, arg3: any): JQuery;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=7&ssc=2&pln=3&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAEjgMyhEcDkArAjgVwFMoBPTAWACgqATQgYwBsBDKQuAc0YgCNnG4AbypxRcYADsYxZM3rsAUgEUipISLGaw3GAApWHAFxxmEkgBoTUDgCZjpi1Y4Bme2YCUx5apIBuDaIAvlTB1JQIupjMAM40mO4AdNoQegCM5jbmzu5AA)

Comment: I've declared it as global right in the file and it seems to work.  Is this likely to cause problems elsewhere down the road?

Comment: That should be fine as long you only ever use this plugin from that one file. Otherwise, you'll probably want to put it in a `.d.ts` file